# Sonatype "Application Health Check" tool does not start

Tags: sonatype

I'd like to try Sonatype's Application Health Check tool and installed the Windows version 2.0.3 on my Win 7 Professional SP1. However, when double-clicking the exe, nothing seems to happen albeit the process is showing up in task view.

So I tried to run the application from command line with my own JRE 1.7.0_80
 (java -jar application-check-2.0.3.jar). Now I see some messages in the DOS box:

```
[ERROR] Failed analytics response. [error = Connect to api.segment.io:443 [api.segment.io/54.68.250.254, api.segment.io/54.69.214.75, api.segment.io/52.10.174.244, api.segment.io/52.10.254.139, api.segment.io/52.25.83.32, api.segment.io/52.26.58.80] failed: connect timed out]
[INFO] Retrying request [attempt 1] ..
[ERROR] Failed analytics response. [error = Connect to api.segment.io:443 [api.segment.io/52.10.254.139, api.segment.io/52.25.83.32, api.segment.io/52.26.58.80, api.segment.io/54.68.250.254, api.segment.io/54.69.214.75, api.segment.io/52.10.174.244] failed: connect timed out]
[INFO] Retrying request [attempt 2] ..
```

I could not find any information about this issue or what it is caused by. Could it be because I'm behind a company firewall? How could I pass proxy server?

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Yes, this is almost certainly caused by your firewall.  Nexus is trying to reach https://rhc-pro.sonatype.com, and it looks like it is being blocked.

Comment: OK... any way I can get around this, like configure proxy settings? Or is the tool just not ready for company use?

Comment: You can try to set a proxy for your java application. Start the Java Control Panel from your System Control Panel, choose network setting from the general tab and configure a proxy. Depending on your proxy solution, this _might_ work.